Hide an individual Product (not a bundle component) in CPQ Quote Line Editor
I'm trying to hide products from the selection list in the CPQ QLE when certain conditions are met. These are not components of bundles, just products.
I have a Product Rule that triggers a Validation when Saved with the conditions:

the Quote is Type = Budget and
The Quote Line has a checkbox marked True (which is a formula referencing a checkbox from the Product record).

However, I'd like to avoid this in the first place and just hide those products from selection. I've tried various combinations of Product Rule Types, Scopes and Evaluation Events, along with Error Conditions looking at the Quote, Product and Quote Line objects. Nothing seems to work to hide the products.
Is it even possible to hide products? Documentation states components can be hidden, deselected, greyed out, etc, but I can't find any reference to just products.
Any assistance on this would be hugely appreciated!

I don't know if this solution would work for your use case, but you could set a special pricebook for this case, using a flow to update the pricebook Id whenever the Quote type & the checkbox value matches the requirement, where the desired product does not have a pricebook entry.

One way that you may want to consider (if this is still an outstanding issue) is to use a Search filter.  Creating a search filter will allow you to filter out those products during the product selection screen, effectively 'hiding' them from the QLE.  Also keep in mind with this solution you will need to find a way to identify these products specifically.
You then may want to consider placing Validation Rules (Product Rules) in place just in case someone clears the filter and selects the Product.  The validation rule will prevent them from saving the Quote.
Hope this helps.
